# Proper way to use modify in getting the next month of given date

Tags: php, datetime

My mind was blown right now.. I couldn't figure out why the next month of January become March. I hope anyone in here can help me and give me explanation why it happened.

I am trying to customize date by next month with its cutoff day where next day of *05* is *20* and *15* is *30*

Here is the code

```
    $cutoff = "2021-01-30";
    $datetime = new DateTime($cutoff);

    echo $datetime->format('Y-m-d')."<br>";
    $day = substr($cutoff, 8);

    if($day == "05")
    {
        $next_cutoff = $datetime->format('Y-m-20');
    }
    elseif($day == "15") 
    {
        $datetime->modify('last day of this month');
        $next_cutoff = (substr($datetime->format('Y-m-d'), 8) <= 30) ? $datetime->format('Y-m-d') : 
        $datetime->format('Y-m-30');
    }
    else
    {
        $datetime->modify('next month');

        $next_cutoff = ($day == "20") ? $datetime->format('Y-m-05') : $datetime->format('Y-m-15');

    }

    echo $next_cutoff;
```

I tried to set the `$cutoff` variable to `$cutoff = "2021-01-28"` and it went fine

[image]

But, when I tried to set it to `$cutoff = "2021-01-29"` and up that's the time the next month became **March**

[image]

I tried, other month also and it works fine. Just this one is the only problem. Is there anyone can help me out there?

Comment: well i think there's no feb 29th, that's why it skips

Comment: @Kevin the date was set to 2021-01-29 not 2021-02-29. It should print 2021-02-15 but i'm getting this problem.

Comment: so you expect 2021-01-29 switched to next month is `2021-02-29`? like i said, there's no 29th of feb. it gets the next valid date which is march 1st (therefore skips the month). so you should switch to the next cutoff

Comment: and got me thinking, shouldn't you be making your conditions `<=` instead of `==`. im not sure why `2021-01-04`'s cutoff should fall to `2021-02-15` when `2021-01-05`'s cutoff is earlier with `2021-01-20`. ‍♂️

Comment: ah.. don't worry about it. it was given by the server. you gave me enough explanation. I ashamed at myself right now but thanks. it will help me grow.

Comment: no need to be ashamed. we all learn everyday

Comment: Yeah... You're the MAN!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change `"next month"` to `"first day of next month"` in your code:

```
// $datetime->modify('next month');
$datetime->modify('first day of next month');
```